# SQL statement dealing with JOINS for PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, select

I have a database structure of the following:

users table:

```
- id
- first_name
- last_name
- fire_id (FOREIGN KEY)
```

matches table:

```
id
winner_id (RELATIONSHIP TO "fire_id" IN USERS TABLE) string
loser_id (RELATIONSHIP TO "fire_id" IN USERS TABLE) string
pot_amount int
player1_id (RELATIONSHIP TO "fire_id" IN USERS TABLE) string
player2_id (RELATIONSHIP TO "fire_id" IN USERS TABLE) string
game_id (RELATIONSHIP TO "id" in GAMES TABLE) int
in_progress (BOOLEAN)
```

games table:

```
id
name
console
```

I am trying to build an SQL statement for PostgreSQL.
Here is what I want to do.
Build a query that gets all the matches that in_progress is false. Also will join the users table and include player1 and IF player2 is not NULL, it will include player2 in their aswell. It also will include the game in the query based on the "game_id" of the match.

If anyone could help me out in building this query I would be greatly appreciative.
Thank you

As of right now I have the following query but it returns a row for player1 and another row for player2

```
SELECT *
FROM matches
JOIN users ON matches.player1_id = users.fire_id OR matches.player2_id = users.fire_id
LEFT JOIN games ON matches.game_id = games.id
```

Comment: please do your homework on your own. Start reading about sql and how to write a query. if you are facing any problems with the output of the query do post the query and the output of the query and we will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join on `users` twice, once for each player. Note that the `join` for player 2 should be a `left join`, as there may not be a second player:

```sql
SELECT    *
FROM      matches
JOIN      users ON matches.player1_id = users.fire_id 
LEFT JOIN users ON matches.player2_id = users.fire_id
LEFT JOIN games ON matches.game_id = games.id
```